# examples such that (i)$F[x]$ is not a field, (ii) $F[x]$ is also a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field.Then we know that $F[x]$ is a Euclidean Domain.But can someone give me few examples such that (i)$F[x]$ is not a field, (ii) $F[x]$ is also a field.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

$F[x]$ is *never* a field, if $F$ is; to see this, try and find a multiplicative inverse for $x$ in $F[x]$; such would have to be a polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$ with $xp(x) = 1$; but $xp(x)$ has no term of degree zero, whereas $1$ has *only* a term of degree zero.***QED.***

The above provides a rich source of examples for $F[x]$ *not* a field! ;-)!!!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial ring F[X] is never a field. Consider the element X. What is it's inverse? It doesn't have one in F[X] (i.e. 1/X isn't in F[X]) and so F[X] can't be field.